# Extract methods of a class from the keys of a dictionary

Tags: python

The idea of the scripts bellow is to extract the keys of the dictionary and have them as methods. The keys represents commands in natural language that will be executed by a specific machine.

The questions are:

1. What needs to be done to see the available commands(which are methods, now) as part of `dir()` or as completion during program editing.
2. I would like to change the values of the commands on the fly.
   Ex: `machine2.move_x()` prints `'MV 12'` but `machine2.move_x('MV 20')` generates `TypeError: <lambda>() takes no arguments (1 given)`.
   I have tried to play with the number of arguments but I haven't got it right.

### machine_ctrl.py

```
class Machine(dict):
    """ Extract dictionary from *machine_cmds.py*
    """
    def __init__(self, machine):
        dct = getattr(__import__("machine_cmds", fromlist=[]), machine)
        super(Machine, self).__init__(dct)

    def __getattr__(self, k):
        """ Defines the names of the methods to be the same as the
        keys of the dictionaries.
        """
        if k in self:
            return lambda: self[k]
        raise TypeError('Example object has not attribute {!r}'.format(k))




if __name__ == '__main__':
    machine1 = Machine('SIEMENS_4A')
    machine2 = Machine('ROLL_X32A')

    machine1.poweron()
    machine1.home()
    machine2.move_x()
```

### machine_cmds.py

```
SIEMENS_4A = {'poweron':'OUTP ON',
              'home' : 'MV 0, 0',
              'identify': '*IDN?'
              }

ROLL_X32A = {'identify': '*IDN?',
             'move_x': 'MV 12'}
```

Comment: Are you using python2.7 or 3+? If you are using both then the `python` tag is enough. If you care only for a specific version than please remove the other version-specific tag (*and* keep the `python` tag).

Comment: @Bakuriu: Oh, ok! I did not know that. I thought that I'll open the question to a broader audience if you put both. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can supply a `__dir__` method to return all available commands:

```
def __dir__(self):
    return sorted(self)
```

This includes the keys of the object in the output of `dir()`.

To support setting, it'd be easier if you replaced the lambda with a nested function; the code is more readable that way:

```
def __getattr__(self, k):
    """ Defines the names of the methods to be the same as the
    keys of the dictionaries.
    """
    if k in self:
        def getter_setter(new_value=None):
            if new_value is None:
                return self[k]
            self[k] = new_value
        return getter_setter
    raise AttributeError(k)
```

I also replaced the `TypeError` with the more applicable `AttributeError`.

Rather than make it a method, you could just return the value directly, and implement a `__setitem__` to support setting:

```
def __getattr__(self, k):
    """ Defines the names of the methods to be the same as the
    keys of the dictionaries.
    """
    if k in self:
        return self[k]
    raise AttributeError(k)

def __setattr__(self, k, v):
    if k in self:
        self[k] = v
    super(Machine, self).__setattr__(k, v)
```

Demo:

```
>>> class Machine(dict):
...     def __init__(self):
...         dct = {'poweron':'OUTP ON', 'home' : 'MV 0, 0', 'identify': '*IDN?'}
...         super(Machine, self).__init__(dct)
...     def __dir__(self):
...         return sorted(self)
...     def __getattr__(self, k):
...         if k in self:
...             def getter_setter(new_value=None):
...                 if new_value is None:
...                     return self[k]
...                 self[k] = new_value
...             return getter_setter
...         raise AttributeError(k)
... 
>>> m = Machine()
>>> dir(m)
['home', 'identify', 'poweron']
>>> m.home
<function Machine.__getattr__.<locals>.getter_setter at 0x10407fe18>
>>> m.home()
'MV 0, 0'
>>> m.home('new value')
>>> m.home()
'new value'
```

And using the `__getattr__` / `__setattr__` approach:

```
>>> class Machine(dict):
...     def __init__(self):
...         dct = {'poweron':'OUTP ON', 'home' : 'MV 0, 0', 'identify': '*IDN?'}
...         super(Machine, self).__init__(dct)
...     def __dir__(self):
...         return sorted(self)
...     def __getattr__(self, k):
...         if k in self:
...             return self[k]
...         raise AttributeError(k)
...     def __setattr__(self, k, v):
...         if k in self:
...             self[k] = v
...         super(Machine, self).__setattr__(k, v)
... 
>>> m = Machine()
>>> m.home
'MV 0, 0'
>>> m.home = 'new value'
>>> m.home
'new value'
```

Comment: Hi Martijn! Let me play with it and I will get back to you. One more thing that I would like to do is to embed some communication protocol as a method such that at the end of , let's say, `machine1.home()` the command will be sent on the wire. Any suggestion?

Comment: If that's a question, as it appear to be, yes! I want to keep things compact and simple from  user's point of view. Ex: Just select the machine together with the command `machine.command(value)`, and user should know that it went on the wire as soon as it pressed `Enter`

Comment: You can just extend the nested function approach here (to give you easy access to the `self` closure) for that, yes.

Comment: I see that for a new value you set it and then invoke it in two steps (1.  `m.home('new value')` , 2. `m.home()` )
 The idea would be to enter a new value and push it on the wire in one single step, just `home('new value')`

Comment: You are free to return it immediately in that case; it was just a choice.

Comment: Great! If you don't mind I will keep the question open until I will get it right as I might be asking for suggestions. I hope you are ok with it!

Comment: @flamenco: follow-up questions are actually best handled as new questions. Short clarifications about the answer are fine, but when we move beyond minor clarifications the comment back-and-forwarding no longer scales.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74140/discussion-between-flamenco-and-martijn-pieters).